# New to eclipse and need guidance

Tags: java, eclipse

So I am writing a game code in eclipse and I was just wondering if I could split up my work in different tabs. An example is that I have all my if statements in one tab and in the next I have another class that I could work with. Because at the moment my code is getting way too long and I would like to be more organized. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by tab? From this, I think you want your code to have more classes and packages?

Comment: You're trying to solve the wrong problem here.  If your code is disorganized and unwieldy, fix **the code** itself, rather than trying to adapt your Eclipse workspace.  If there is a specific issue you are having, show us the code and maybe we can suggest some ways to help you organize it better.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're willing to help you. Please take the time to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54968447/edit) the question accordingly. Please create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and give sample inputs, outputs and the error messages you get, if any. This will help us to determine what is going on and improve your chances to get an answer.

Comment: Hey people sorry for confusing you. What I mean is that if I seperate a class from my code too another tab(you know tabs like on Google Chrome you can have different tabs) how do I call that class back. It's like using Html and adding css. You use different tabs. I hope this made you understand something more. Thanks for taking your time

Comment: Could it be as simple as clicking on the tab (same way you'd switch between tabs in Chrome)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a simple game on a canvas, you could use the following tabs (classes):

**MainThread** - this class updates the canvas (let's say) at 60 fps, it calls `update()` and `draw(Canvas canvas)` in the `GamePanel` class.

**GamePanel** - this class has a `GameplayScene` field, the `GameplayScene` instance is the scene that is currently being displayed on the canvas. In the `GamePanel` class, you have (at least) two methods: `update()` and `draw(Canvas canvas)`, which call the same methods in the `GameplayScene` instance.

**GameplayScene** - you could make this an interface, so you could have multiple classes implementing it. You could also have just one `GameplayScene`, it doesn't have to be an interface then.

You could have multiple classes that implement `GameplayScene`, so you have multiple scenes, for example, an item shop, the main menu, or a level.

In each scene you have, again, the `update()` and `draw(Canvas canvas)`  methods, which call the same methods in instances of `GameObject`. A scene class is responsible for keeping track of the player's score, when the player dies, or that the game restarts when the player dies.

**GameObject** - I would make this an interface, so you could have multiple objects implementing the interface.

A game object could be the player, an obstacle, a button, an enemy, whatever is drawn onto the canvas.

In the game object's `update()` method, you (for example) set the object's position based on some calculations, or you test if an enemy collides with the player.
In the game object's `draw(Canvas canvas)` method, the only thing you do is drawing the object onto the `canvas`. You do the calculations in the `update()` method.